# android: Deleting an app does not remove login data

Tags: android

I have a strange behavior on a Galaxy S22/Android12 that I started using yesterday. Everything was set up, so no data transfer was made.

I installed the app "Spontacts", logged in there with email address and password and wondered why I do not receive push messages. So I uninstalled the app and installed it again.
After the reinstallation, I start the app and am immediately logged in.

No matter what I do, the app does not clear the login session, even if I log out, then uninstall and reinstall the app, I am immediately logged back in the first time I launch the app.

Support can't explain this so far and says they can't debug anything unless they can trace it with their own device.

Which all didn't help:

- Logging out of the app
- Uninstalling the app
- Clearing the "memory" of the app in the system settings under Apps
- Deleting the cache partition
- Reboot the phone

I think it's totally crazy that there are session remnants left here when deleting the app. The support thinks it could be the cache of the WebView, whose data I have deleted via "Apps".

Does anyone have any idea what else I can do to get rid of the leftover data of the app?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the app has enabled `allowBackup` feature
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup

It allows the application to participate in the backup and restore infrastructure.
And it automatically backs up a user's data from apps that target and run on Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher. Android preserves app data by uploading it to the user's Google Drive—where it's protected by the user's Google account credentials.

[More details about auto backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup).

So, the app data is stored with the device backup in your Google Drive. I think you can delete a backup to clear the app credentials.

Comment: Thanks, deleting the backup in the Google Drive app did not remove the login information. Updating the WebView component to the beta version ended the strange behavior. After reverting to the stable version, the strange behavior no longer occurred.